# Moving Screen Position Entirely

Tags: screen, touchscreen, broken-screen, touch, google-pixel-4a

My phone screen broke (I dropped the phone) - I wanted to repair it, but it costs a lot.

The company where I bought fixed the screen for me, but it doesn't work properly still - at least not 100%.

[image]

Marked part of the screen on the image is not responding to touch.

The solution I came up with is to somehow in Android Developer settings move the screen these 50px down, so it starts under the camera, and so I can use the phone like nothing ever happened.

Do you guys know how it can be done?

I looked everywhere but didn't find a solution ;/

Thank you in advance!

- **PS. The image below shows basically what I want to accomplish:**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this https://mashtips.com/hide-display-notch-and-cutouts-on-pixel/ ?

Comment: I did it, thank you very much, but sadly it's more than I thought it is. I also changed screen DPI, that's how it looks like, but it still has to be moved down to work properly: https://i.postimg.cc/Rh6r82xL/298362512-430104902505949-7469116080281976904-n.png

Comment: Ok, I was able to change screen resolution via ADB shell commands, not it looks like this: https://scontent.fpoz4-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/299264174_742590493489957_9171596892222942583_n.jpg?_nc_cat=107&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=ae9488&_nc_ohc=2gnF4R8zn1oAX9_xw9J&_nc_ht=scontent.fpoz4-1.fna&oh=03_AVIz0sfmHtqJYczmfp__KQUJPAd3VfWh8_XaVER9hMy4AQ&oe=63245F37

Comment: But I have no idea how can I change placement of the screen to move whole screen down, then it would be perfect

Comment: I find out the solution (ALMOST) - it's overscan option, for example: adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,-200

Comment: Sadly, it does not work since some Android version (unknown command prompt)